# php форма c textarea и запись каждой строки в переменную

Tags: php, json, api

Не очень понимаю как привести код к виду где каждая новая строка их textarea будет записывать в новую переменную, или цикл что бы быть обработанной api.

Иметься код, формы:

```
<form action="2.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="10" cols="75" name="name" ></textarea>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Код обработчика:

```
   <?php

include "API.php";

$api = new API();
$api->access_token = '236a054c';

$var = $_POST['name'];


$data = $api->getFilesInfo(["$var"]);

if (!array_key_exists('files', $data)) {
    echo 'There is no files in response' . PHP_EOL;
}


foreach ($data['files'] as $file) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo (array_key_exists('id', $file) ? $file['id'] : 'ID not found')  . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

API отвечают так:

```
    {
   "status":"success",
   "code":200,
   "files": [
      {
         "id":"4632a04bb0d2b",
         "name":"test",
         }
      }
   ]
```

Так вот, все мои варианты обрабатывали только первое значение, как обработать все значения которые будут написаны в тестовую форму с новой строки

Answer (score 0):

В `$_POST['name']` вам прилетит текст из textarea. Каждая новая строка в нём отделена от предыдущей символом (или несколькими) [переноса строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Вам надо [разбить](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split) текст по символу переноса строки и вы получите отдельные строки

```php
<?php

$vals = preg_split('/\R/', $_POST['name']?? '', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Я возможно не так пояснил. Когда я запрашиваю api getFilesInfo - он возвращает информацию о файле, я получаю одно значение, но api умеет возвращать сразу несколько значений. Если я задам в поле $data = $api->getFilesInfo(["$var"]); - вместо переменной $var эти значения: $api->getFilesInfo(["file1id","file2id","file3id]); то я получу информацию о трех разных файлах, вот я не понимаю как записать код таким образом, что бы при введении в форму с новой строки file1id,file2id,file3id, или через запятую эти данные, что бы api вернул мне 3 файла, а сейчас я получаю только информацию о первом файле

Comment: @Spirg ну так вы получите значения `$vals` и передадите их в апи `$api->getFilesInfo($vals);`. Что не так?